# HTML 5 and java integration

Tags: java, html, jaxb

i need to use html 5 for GUI and JAXB framework ( eclipse ) for coding. i am not able to understand how would i integrate both ?

I appreciate if any of you suggest a good idea

Answer (score 1):

The two have nothing to do with each other. Besides: Even JAXB and Eclipse have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a summary of where each of the pieces fit:

**HTML 5**

You can use HTML 5 to create some fairly sophisticated clients.  You can use JavaScript to implement your logic, and REST calls, WebSockets, or Server Sent Events (SSE) to communicate with your server.

**JAXB**

The communication between client and server can be some sort of XML or JSON message.  JAXB can  be used to convert server side objects to either XML or JSON.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html

JAXB is also the default binding layer for JAX-RS, which is the Java EE standard for creating RESTful services:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

**Eclipse**

The Eclipse IDE can be used to build the Java and HTML 5 aspects of your application.  The Eclipse runtime also runtime components such as [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) that you may find useful (I'm the MOXy tech lead).